# Is there a "cleaner" way to substitute stdin into a string in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-substitution

When bash scripting, I frequently find myself doing something like this:

```
bc <<< "64*`cat`"
```

or

```
bc <<< "64*`dd`"
```

if I want to multiply stdin by 64. Is there a better way to substitute stdin into a string (or into a command line, such as in `seq 1 2 $(cat)`)?

Comment: What's wrong with `read`?

Comment: ^^ I would also have tried this: `read calc; bc <<< "64 * $calc"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly *more efficient* way to do it, assuming your platform represents stdin as ([character special](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60147/54804)) file `/dev/stdin` (which is quite likely):

```
$ echo 2 | bc <<< "64 * $(</dev/stdin)"
128

$ echo 5 | seq 1 2 "$(</dev/stdin)"
1
3
5
```

However, while this avoids a call to an external utility such as `cat`, it is *more verbose*.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using string expansion:

```
(echo -n '64*'; cat) | bc
```

But for a simple multiplication you actually don't need to use `bc` and you can multiply directly in bash:

```
read a
echo "$((a*64))"
```